# Transaction callback fired multiple times

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, transactions, callback

I've ran into some very strange behaviour of my app today:
I've got this function to create The tables, and then, when succeeded, going on in the code.

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newsDetail(id unique, title, text, created, createdTS, imageSmall, imageBig, facebook, gameNumber)');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lastModified(id unique, ts)');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teams(pos unique, name, games, gd, points, s, snv, gl, glo, goals)');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS players(number unique, name, nickname, birthdate, height, married, children, profession, clubs, position, image)');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS games(id unique, home, away, score, date, shortDate)');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS galleryCategories(id unique, name, date, thumb, ordering)');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS galleryImages(id unique, url, description, catid, ordering)');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS videos(id unique, url, title, image)');
}, errorCB, function () {
    loadData('newslist', createNewslist, true);
    loadData('refresh', loadNewOnes, true);
});
```

The Problem now is, that the Succes Callback function is called 8 times. Why is that? I've been using this code for a few months now and never had this problem before. Has anybody ever ran into something similair yet? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, you added some code that calls that function several times. What can happen is that since that function is asynchronous, if you loop through it or run code that continously call that function, that code will not block and wait for your function to finish executing. Instead it get's called multiple times without knowing why it's happening.

Did you happen to write tests to surround the issue so you knew what was being broken?